# C++/Template related compiler warnings with Eigen library and ARM compiler (logical 'and' applied to non-boolean constant [-Wlogical-op])

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I use the Eigen algebra library and get dozens of pages (template pain) of compiler warnings (see below).
Just wanted to use Eigen in a template class with ARM compiler. 
Seems like these messages are compiler related (but I was not really validating it). Actually, the code works but the warnings make me crazy, because I don't really understand them. 
Does someone know what is the problem and how I can fix these warnings?

I get these warning at any place, I use Eigen Matrix functions. Here I present a simple example which spawns them:

```
Eigen::Vector3f v3(2,2,2);
std::cout << "v3 length: " << v3.norm() << std::endl;
```

Warnings like this:

```
Eigen::Vector3f v3(2,2,2);
std::cout << "v3 length: " << v3.norm() << std::endl;

In file included from /home/dgrat/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Eigen/eigen/Eigen/Core:315:0,
             from /home/dgrat/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Eigen/AP_Eigen.h:25,
             from EigenDemoMini.cpp:6:
/home/dgrat/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h: In instantiation of 'struct Eigen::internal::redux_traits<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<float>, Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs2_op<float>, const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> > >':
/home/dgrat/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h:330:34:   required from 'typename Eigen::internal::result_of<BinaryOp(typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar)>::type Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::redux(const Func&) const [with BinaryOp = Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<float>; Derived = Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs2_op<float>, const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> >; typename Eigen::internal::result_of<BinaryOp(typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar)>::type = float]'
/home/dgrat/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h:363:62:   required from 'typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::sum() const [with Derived = Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_abs2_op<float>, const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> >; typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar = float]'
/home/dgrat/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Dot.h:115:48:   required from 'typename Eigen::NumTraits<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar>::Real Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::squaredNorm() const [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>; typename Eigen::NumTraits<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar>::Real = float]'
/home/dgrat/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Dot.h:128:27:   required from 'typename Eigen::NumTraits<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar>::Real Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::norm() const [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>; typename Eigen::NumTraits<typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar>::Real = float]'
EigenDemoMini.cpp:16:43:   required from here
/home/dgrat/ardupilot/libraries/AP_Eigen/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Redux.h:40:41: warning: logical 'and' applied to non-boolean constant [-Wlogical-op]
 MayLinearVectorize = MightVectorize && (int(Derived::Flags)&LinearAccessBit),
                                     ^
Building /tmp/EigenDemoMini.build/EigenDemoMini.elf
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler find it suspicious that a && is applied to a bool and what seems to be a int right operand.
It does not seem related to your code but merely to the implementation of the Eigen library that is not warning free for your specific compiler and compiler version.
You can remove this warning with the option -Wno-logical-op.

**-Wno-logical-op**: Disables the warning that warns suspicious uses of logical operators in expressions. This includes using logical operators in contexts where a bit-wise operator is likely to be expected

Comment: This I tried, but this compiler parameter is ignored. I still get these warnings. Looks like a bug in ARM GCC.